# How can we make a spherical shell uniformly charged?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, charge, measurements, density

Today, I was studying [Newton's shell theorem (ellectrostatics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem). There we considered a spherical shell of uniform surface charge density.

Then a question popped out in my mind:

How can we make the spherical shell uniformly charged?

Also, if we are given a random spherical shell, can we cut the shell into pieces and then measure the charge in each one of them? How?

Comment: Can you explain why you think the charge wouldn't be evenly distributed? For example are you thinking that it's because the charge is made up from electrons and therefore isn't continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make the spherical shell uniformly charged is to make it out of a conducting material. Any charge will then distribute itself uniformly, for reasons explained in another answer.

If you want to charge an insulating sphere uniformly, you are going to have quite a challenge ensuring that the charge is applied evenly, but it is more of an engineering challenge than a physics one.

Any cutter must of course not transfer any charge between itself and the sphere, either through conduction or friction. Maybe an optical or infrared laser might do the job.

Answer (score 1):

A conductor can be defined as a material in which charges can move freely.

When you deposit some charges onto a conductive material, they will naturally move around so to find the configuration that makes the electric field inside the conductor vanish. 
This is easy to see because if there where an electric field due to the charges I deposited, the charges themselves would move around according to the field itself.

According to this principle, if I charge a conductive sphere or a conductive spherical shell, the charges will naturally be distributed uniformly on the skin of the conductor because that is the configuration that makes the electric field inside the material vanish and that minimises the energy (the charges are the farthest away possible).